# Tag-wiki excerpt editing area overlaps sidebar

Tags: bug, editing, design, tag-wikis

I was just fixing a minor grammatical issue in the tag excerpt for [divisor-sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisor-sum) when I noticed the following:

[image]

A cursory glance at the relevant HTML code did not reveal an immediate cause for this bug.

---

**Edit**: Just noticed a similar bug occurring for the "custom" flag text area.

Comment: Confirmed. Firefox/Iceweasel 21.0 on Debian.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot that one. I use Chrome latest, Win 7.

Comment: That was always that way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The fact that it was always that way doesn't mean that it shouldn't be fixed ;).

Comment: @rbm: Just making an observation...